# Merge Sort of a linked list java: Stack overflow

Tags: java, sorting, stack-overflow, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a linked list merge sort.

Here's the class I'm trying to do the merge sort in.

```
/**
 * CS 200 Colorado State University, Fall 2011
 */

public class Member {

private String userID;
private String first;
private String last;
private EdgeStack edgeStack;

public void sortScore(Member member){
    // calling a helper method
    // this greedy method takes all the creds 
    edgeStack = sortEdgeStack(member); 
}

private EdgeStack sortEdgeStack(Member member)
{
    // our temp stacks
    EdgeStack tempEdgeStack_A = new EdgeStack();
    EdgeStack tempEdgeStack_B = new EdgeStack();

    // our return value 
    EdgeStack result = null; 
    // storing the size of the stack 
    int sizeOfStack = member.getEdgeStack().getSize();
    // base case 
    if(sizeOfStack<0){
        return null; 
    }
    // our true base case
    else if(sizeOfStack==1) 
    { 
        // init stack
        EdgeStack base = new EdgeStack(); 

        base.push(member.getEdgeStack().pop());
        return base; 
    }
    else
    {

        // pop and store 
        for(int i = 0; i < (sizeOfStack / 2); i++)
        {
            tempEdgeStack_A.push(member.getEdgeStack().pop()); 
        }
        // pop and store into b
        for(int j = (sizeOfStack/2)+1; j < sizeOfStack; j++)
        {
            tempEdgeStack_B.push(member.getEdgeStack().pop());
        }

        tempEdgeStack_A = sortEdgeStack(member);
        tempEdgeStack_B = sortEdgeStack(member);
        result = merge(tempEdgeStack_A,tempEdgeStack_B); 
        return result;
    }
}


private EdgeStack merge(EdgeStack tempEdgeStack_A, EdgeStack tempEdgeStack_B) {

    EdgeStack result = new EdgeStack(); 

    // while either or
    while(tempEdgeStack_A.getSize()> 0 || tempEdgeStack_B.getSize() > 0)
    {
        // if both are bigger then 0 
        if(tempEdgeStack_A.getSize()> 0 && tempEdgeStack_B.getSize() > 0)
        {
            if(tempEdgeStack_A.peek().getEdgeRank()<=tempEdgeStack_B.peek().getEdgeRank())
            {
                // adds b to result
                result.push(tempEdgeStack_A.pop()); 
            }
            else 
            {
                result.push(tempEdgeStack_B.pop());
            }
        }
        // these elses cover if A or B are > 0 but A or B is also less then or equal too 0; 
        else if(tempEdgeStack_A.getSize()> 0)
        {
            while(tempEdgeStack_A.iterator().hasNext())
            {
                result.push(tempEdgeStack_A.iterator().next()); 
            }
        }
        else if(tempEdgeStack_B.getSize()> 0)
        {
            while(tempEdgeStack_B.iterator().hasNext())
            {
                result.push(tempEdgeStack_B.iterator().next()); 
            }
        }
    }

    return result; 
}
 }
```

Here's the stack class (that implements a linked list). Why am I getting a stack overflow error?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

/**
 * CS 200 Colorado State University, Fall 2011
 */

public class EdgeStack {


private LinkedList<Edge> llist=new LinkedList<Edge>();

public EdgeStack(){
    //add your code
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return llist.isEmpty();
}

public void push(Edge e){
    llist.add(e);
}

public Edge getIndexAt(int n){
    return llist.get(n);
}

public Edge pop(){
    return llist.remove();
}

public Edge peek(){

    return llist.getLast();
}

public int getSize(){
    return llist.size();
}

//  public Edge peek(int n){
//      LinkedList<Edge> temp=llist;
//      return temp.peek();
//  }


public LinkedList<Edge> popAll(){
    LinkedList<Edge> temp=llist;
    llist=null;
    return temp;    }

public ListIterator<Edge> iterator()
{
    return llist.listIterator();
}

}
```

Comment: Here some words of advice: If you post that much code consider usinga code pasting service like https://gist.github.com/. Also the code you posted does not compile because the Edge class is missing and there is now way for me to test it because there is no main method to be run. If you get an exception in a Java program make sure to post the stacktrace as well. People are usually glad to help, but you need to show some effort as well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
    else if(tempEdgeStack_A.getSize()> 0)
    {
        while(tempEdgeStack_A.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            result.push(tempEdgeStack_A.iterator().next()); 
        }
    }
    else if(tempEdgeStack_B.getSize()> 0)
    {
        while(tempEdgeStack_B.iterator().hasNext())
        {
            result.push(tempEdgeStack_B.iterator().next()); 
        }
    }
```

You don't remove entries from the stacks, so the loop doesn't stop.